# IntelliJ Idea - How to enable gradle wrapper

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Importing gradle project into intelliJ IDEA : use default gradle wrapper option (not configured for the current project) is disabled.

How to solve this?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you ask why this option is grayed out?
[image]

That because the your project doesn`t have a wrapper.
You can add a wrapper by using the task

> gradle wrapper

This will add a gradle directory , a file named gradlew.bat and one named gradlew

after this you can reimport your project or 
change it in your settings control + shift + s

[image]

Comment: To run the task "gradle wrapper", press Ctrl twice to open the Run Anything dialog. Then type the command and press Enter.